# What is the correct usage of GetLastError and FormatMessage in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, error-handling

I have a problem using a third-party component in Delphi 2006 (also Delphi 7), in which I get an "Unspecified Error" when executing a function call to that component.  Do you have example code that utilises GetLastError and FormatMessage in Delphi, that would allow me to access more information about the error ?  TIA :)

Comment: You are going to have to add more context to your question. What does your code actually look like that is failing? `"Unspecified error"` is an actual system error message (for the `E_FAIL` error code), so it is likely that you will not be able to get more details about the failure, depending on what exactly you are doing. Where are you getting the "Unspecified error" message from exactly? And what makes you think the 3rd party component utilizes `(Get|Set)LastError()` to give you more details than you already have?

Comment: Hi Remy, thanks for your comment :). I actually posted this way back in 2009 so I can't remember the context, much less still have the code. Cheers !

Comment: you are right. My bad. I did not notice the date on the question. I think dummzeuch's recent edit to his answer brought this question to the top of my feed. I'll have to pay better attention to dates.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

There is an integrated helper function in Delphi: `SysErrorMessage`. It's essentially a wrapper to `FormatMessage`, but much simpler to use in your case. Just provide the error code you need a textual description for.

For example you can use this to display the last error:

```
ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError))
```

If you want to raise an exception with this message, it's even simpler:

```
RaiseLastOSError;
```

**Important**: Make sure that there is no additional API call between the failing function and your call of `GetLastError`, otherwise the last error will be reset.

Comment: Note: Using a resource string will result in an API call, so you lose the error code!

Answer (score 13):

While DR is correct, there is a problem with this approach: It does not allow you to specify the context in which the error occurred. Ever seen the error "An API function failed." whithout being any wiser which function it was and where it happended?

That's why I wrote the RaiseLastOsErrorEx and Win32CheckEx functions:

```
procedure RaiseLastOsErrorEx(const _Format: string);
begin
  RaiseLastOsErrorEx(GetLastError, _Format);
end;

procedure RaiseLastOsErrorEx(_ErrorCode: integer; _Format: string); overload;
var
  Error: EOSError;
begin
  if _ErrorCode <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
    Error := EOSError.CreateFmt(_Format, [_ErrorCode, SysErrorMessage(_ErrorCode)])
  else
    Error := EOsError.CreateFmt(_Format, [_ErrorCode, _('unknown OS error')]);
  Error.ErrorCode := _ErrorCode;
  raise Error;
end;

function GetLastOsError(out _Error: string; const _Format: string = ''): DWORD;
begin
  Result := GetLastOsError(GetLastError, _Error, _Format);
end;

function GetLastOsError(_ErrCode: integer; out _Error: string; const _Format: string = ''): DWORD;
var
  s: string;
begin
  Result := _ErrCode;
  if Result <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
    s := SysErrorMessage(Result)
  else
    s := _('unknown OS error');
  if _Format <> '' then
    try
      _Error := Format(_Format, [Result, s])
    except
      _Error := s;
    end else
    _Error := s;
end;

function Win32CheckEx(_RetVal: BOOL; out _ErrorCode: DWORD; out _Error: string;
  const _Format: string = ''): BOOL;
begin
  Result := _RetVal;
  if not Result then
    _ErrorCode := GetLastOsError(_Error, _Format);
end;
```

(They are part of unit u_dzMiscUtils of my dzLib library available here:
https://osdn.net/projects/dzlib-tools/svn/view/dzlib/trunk/src/u_dzMiscUtils.pas?view=markup&root=dzlib-tools#l313

Comment: Thanks very much for the additional code and the links :)  +1

Comment: A general exception framework like madExcept would be even better.

Comment: @DR: Yes, maybe, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: Well, in that case: Neither was "specifying the context in which the error occurred"...