# How not to show system messages - Delphi

Tags: delphi, file, delphi-2010

Consider this part of code:

```
Try
  arqTXT.LoadFromFile(LogPath);
finally
  ShowMessage(" The log file could not be found. Check if the service is running. ");
end;
```

After my message, a system message appears with the message: Cannot open file "C:\log.txt". Is there a way to not show this system message?

**I'm using Delphi 2010**

Thanks.

Comment: A message of what kind? And what IDE are you using? I know from RAD Studio XE2, that it outputs all exceptions once they are raised, regardless of if they're caught or not. That's a matter of settings. It won't appear in the 'real' program.

Comment: I'm using Delphi 2010. I just edited my question.

Comment: It will only show on debug mode. You can also disable it in settings.

Comment: That error is likely because the file you are trying to read is already opened by some other program.

Comment: @Blobby - or the file doesn't exist etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would like to trap that specific exception (`EInOutError` if I remember correctly) and let other exceptions that occurred to remain unmuted. So if you get some other exception (e.g. `EOutOfMemory`) if wont get "swallowed" leaving you with seemingly working but broken code.

```
try
  ..
except
  on E: EInOutError do
        begin
          ..
        end;
end;
```

You can have many exceptions handlers in one construct. Any unhandled exceptions will continue to propagate outside of the try .. except block, until caught elsewhere (e.g. by default exception handler that shows the error box).

Comment: There is no need for `else raise;'. Any exception that doesn't descend from EInOutError will "fall through" without it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things to point out. As other answers/comments explain, you should be wrapping your code inside of a `try..except` block instead of a `try..finally` block. I'm not understanding how your code example is supposed to work, because as it's currently written, your message will always show, whether there was an exception or not. It should look something more like...

```
try
  arqTXT.LoadFromFile(LogPath);
except
  on E: EInOutError do begin
    ShowMessage('The log file could not be found. Check if the service is running. Message: '
      + E.Message);
  end
end;
```

That code will catch and handle I/O exceptions. You would use a different exception type instead of `EInOutError` to handle different types of exceptions, or the dirty way is to use `on E: Exception` to catch all types. You can also identify the specific error code using [GetLastError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669073/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-getlasterror-and-formatmessage-in-delphi) and further recognize / log this error code to know exactly what's wrong (File missing, read-only, etc.), assuming that an I/O exception has occured.

[Here's a good article explaining how to handle exceptions in Delphi.](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/errorexception.htm)

The other thing to point out is when you see the exceptions. When you're in Debug mode (running application from the IDE), it will show all exceptions by default, even the ones that you don't see when your application runs on its own. [You can disable this in the IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858319/turn-off-delphi-exceptions-in-run-time-in-delphi). That article is for Delphi 2007, but I'm pretty sure it should apply for 2010 as well, because the same options are in Delphi XE2.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Certainly there's more to handling exceptions than just that, but for someone who appears to be a beginner, I'm just trying to keep it simple. I could have used `MessageDlg` instead of `ShowMessage` too, or re-written the entire message to make more sense, or use `GetLastError` and write a `case` statement to handle different types of I/O errors. But yes, handling specific exception types is the *proper* way to do it.

Comment: Well, you can't use GetLastError since you don't know whether or not your are getting the error code for the most recently called API function. Krom's code is much better.

Comment: I've modified it to emphasize this. I also realized that " was being used instead of ' for the string.

Answer (score -1):

Solve it using

```
try

exception
on e: exception do
ShowMessage("My Message");
```

Instead of Try/Finally.

Comment: Had to give -1, you got the gist, but no explanation, and code is incomplete and doesn't make much sense (what is the first `exception` there for?)

Comment: I guess he meant `try .. except` construct

Comment: @Daniel If your problem was solved by an answer that someone else posted (Krom) then you should accept their answer, not post another answer with the same solution. StackOverflow expects that you accept the appropriate answer (clicking the checkmark next to it). I've also answered in more detail.